# Change of class on an event listener is only temporary, classList.replace is only for one click, how to make it permanent

Tags: javascript

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I wanted to create a simple app for drawing by coloring the background of squares by clicking on them. I added a click event on every li which changes the background-color by adding a class. However, I'd like to take it to the next level by adding 4 buttons that would change the colors of the hightlight. Can anyone help me with that?

So my problem is: How to click a button (li in the header) that will select the color for my original event listener on ul class=grid li?

```
 <header>
      <ul class="header">
        <li class="black">Black</li>
        <li class="red">Red</li>
        <li class="blue">Blue</li>
        <li class="orange">Orange</li>
      </ul>
    </header>
    <ul class="grid">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      .......
```

```
const myElements = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
```

```
for (let i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
  myElements[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    let selected = myElements[i];
    selected.classList.toggle("highlight");
  });
}
```

I tried (remove and add new class, replace class, toggle)

```
black.addEventListener("click", function () {
  selected.classList.replace("highlight", "black");
});
```

But the change of background color is only one-off. I want to new class become permanent.
1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgg87.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding event listeners to both your `ul.header li` and `ul.grid li` you will achieve this. `ul.header li` click event listener will save the color you want and the `ul.grid li` click will use that saved color to apply it.

```js
var selcolor = '';

const colorbtns = document.querySelectorAll('ul.header > li');
const griditems = document.querySelectorAll('ul.grid > li');

colorbtns.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    selcolor = e.target.className;
    console.log(selcolor);
  });
});

griditems.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
       if(el.classList.length <= 0) {
           el.classList.add(selcolor);
       }
       else {
           el.className = "";
       }
   });
});
```

```css
.header li {
  display:inline-block;
  color:#fff;
  padding:5px;
}

.grid li {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.black { background-color:black; }
.red { background-color:red; }
.blue { background-color:blue; }
.orange { background-color:orange; }
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="header">
    <li class="black">Black</li>
    <li class="red">Red</li>
    <li class="blue">Blue</li>
    <li class="orange">Orange</li>
  </ul>
</header>
<ul class="grid">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

Updated the code

```
el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    el.classList.add(selcolor);
});
```

To

```
el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if(el.classList.length <= 0) {
        el.classList.add(selcolor);
    }
    // this else statement will clear the color on second click if theres already one color assigned
    else {
       el.className = "";
    }
  });
```

That way you can only assign the color once as per your comment

> But the change of background color is only one-off

Comment: I'm new to JS. But how to remove the color when you click second time on the same or add the color from another button on the previously clicked one.

Comment: @TomDev Do you want to to clear the color when you click a second time no matter what color is selected or only if the same color is initially selected? Lets say I click BLACK and then click one of the grid squares, it will apply BLACK, you want it to clear when the grid square is clicked again, and then you can assign a new color? OR lets say i click BLACK and then a grid square and then i click RED and the same grid square does it stay black or change to red?

Comment: I'm creating this app for my daughter. If she makes a mistake, I want her to be able to correct it by undoing the move. I guess I could add another button with the class .white. That should do the trick as well.

Comment: You could, or you can simply add an else statement after the `if(el.classList.length <= 0) {` row. Basically `if(el.classList.length <= 0) { el.classList.add(selcolor); } else { el.className = ""; }` that else statement will CLEAR the color in the square clicked if theres one assigned

Comment: el.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (el.classList.length <= 0) {
    el.classList.add(selcolor);
  } else {
    el.className = "";
  }
}); doesn't undo the click and doesn't allow to change the background for another

Comment: @TomDev I've updated the code snipped in my answer. Run it again, click a color, assign it to a square and then click the square again that color should be cleared. And then you can assign it another color.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you should better use Query Selectors in JavaScript.

```
const myElements = document.querySelectorAll("div.grid > li");
```

You can read more on this here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector and
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: It think you meant ul.grid>li. But what I want to achieve is that when I click on the button Black or button Red in the header. I want to add the class to let selected. So that when I click on the button Black (one click event), I want to be able to select myElement and change their background into black. How to handle two event listeners?

Comment: I took out the let selected; from the function; And added a new event listener:   black.addEventListener("click", function () {
  selected.classList.toggle("black");
});   But it changes the previously selected element but the change of color is one-shot and then the .black class doesn't work any more